# ios 13 PHImageManager.default().requestImage and Fusuma

Tags: ios, ios13, phimagemanager

i am using Fusuma pod for my project, but with the last iOS 13 there is one bug related to image which is selected from Gallery.

exactly saying, if selected image is from Gallery (on iphone device with ios 13, not simulator), then the dimensions of image are width:39 and height:39, functions below are ***Fusuma***'s , located in ***FusumaViewController***

```
private func requestImage(with asset: PHAsset, cropRect: CGRect, completion: @escaping (PHAsset, UIImage) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async(execute: {
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
            options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
            options.normalizedCropRect = cropRect
            options.resizeMode = .exact

            let targetWidth  = floor(CGFloat(asset.pixelWidth) * cropRect.width)
            let targetHeight = floor(CGFloat(asset.pixelHeight) * cropRect.height)
            let dimensionW   = max(min(targetHeight, targetWidth), 1024 * UIScreen.main.scale)
            let dimensionH   = dimensionW * self.getCropHeightRatio()

            let targetSize   = CGSize(width: dimensionW, height: dimensionH)

            PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options) { result, info in
                guard let result = result else { return }

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    completion(asset, result)
                })
            }
        })
    }

    private func fusumaDidFinishInMultipleMode() {
        guard let view = albumView.imageCropView else { return }

        let normalizedX = view.contentOffset.x / view.contentSize.width
        let normalizedY = view.contentOffset.y / view.contentSize.height
        let normalizedWidth  = view.frame.width / view.contentSize.width
        let normalizedHeight = view.frame.height / view.contentSize.height

        let cropRect = CGRect(x: normalizedX,
                              y: normalizedY,
                              width: normalizedWidth,
                              height: normalizedHeight)

        var images = [UIImage]()
        var metaData = [ImageMetadata]()

        for asset in albumView.selectedAssets {
            requestImage(with: asset, cropRect: cropRect) { asset, result in
                images.append(result)
                metaData.append(self.getMetaData(asset: asset))

                if asset == self.albumView.selectedAssets.last {
                    self.doDismiss {
                        self.delegate?.fusumaMultipleImageSelected(images, source: self.mode, metaData: metaData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

requestImage(...) function returns incorrect image size

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says `PHImageManager` may call `requestImage` completion multiple times and the final call should have an image with a requested `targetSize`.